# How to get the fully qualified name of method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Let's say that I've got a method available in my workspace in Ruby.  Is there a command I can use that will recover the fully qualified name of the method?

I'm looking for something similar to the [which](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) function in Matlab, that returns an unambiguous name for any argument it's given.

I ask because I'm writing a test in Cucumber that needs to send particular GET and POST requests. I have both `get` and `post` methods in my workspace, but I didn't import them myself and so I don't know where they came from. I want to look at the documentation for these methods. In order to find the documentation, I need to know what module they're defined in. I'm trying to get the fully qualified names in order to figure out which module they're from.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/)?

Comment: Hadn't heard of it before, but I just tried it and it did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Andrew Marshall left a comment that pointed me in the right direction.

First I installed [pry](http://pryrepl.org/), by including it in my gemfile and running `bundle install`.

Then I inserted `binding.pry` into my test code. This dropped me into a pry session when I ran my tests.

In the pry session I typed the [`ls` command](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/State-navigation#wiki-Ls), which listed all the variables in my context.  I found `get` and `post` under `Rack::Test::Methods#methods`.

```
Rack::Test::Methods#methods: _current_session_names  authorize  basic_authorize  build_rack_mock_session  build_rack_test_session  clear_cookies  current_session  delete  digest_authorize  follow_redirect!  get  head  header  last_request  last_response  options  post  put  rack_mock_session  rack_test_session  request  set_cookie  with_session
```

So, one way to find out the FQN of a method in your workspace is to run Pry's `ls` command, and then examine the output.

Comment: Come to think of it, I guess you could also find out where a method's defined by running a debugger, stepping into the method, and then looking at the stack trace. That's probably a better solution.

Comment: First off, Pry is a debugger (it just offers a lot more than a normal debugger). Secondly, you can use Pry to find the documentation for a method, simply type: `show-doc method_name` to view the docs. also, `show-source method_name` to show the source.

Comment: Hmm... I tried both `show-doc get` and `show-source get`.  `show-doc` said it couldn't find any documentation. `show-source` only gave me a snippet from `forwardable.rb` which didn't have anything to do with making http requests.  So neither of these methods were of much help to me (maybe I'm not using them properly? I'm new to RoR.)  Good point about Pry.