# Get the fully qualified name of method

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to obtain the string representation of fully qualified path to the method?

Consider following IRB session:

```
> foo = File.stat("/")
> magic(foo.ctime) or foo.ctime.magic
=> "File::Stat#ctime"
```

Is there any built-in function that does the "magic"? If not, can I get the string dynamically by doing some reflection?

note: I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255303/how-to-get-the-fully-qualified-name-of-method-in-ruby), but I can't use the pry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might call [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-method), returning an instance of [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html):

```
foo.method(:ctime)
#⇒ File::Stat#ctime()
```

The fully qualified method name might be extracted e.g. from a `Method#to_s`:

```
foo.method(:ctime).to_s[/(?<=\A#<Method: ).*(?=>)\z/]
#⇒ "File::Stat#ctime"
```

I am not aware of any ability to get the fq-name directly from `Method` instance, without this regexp trick.

As properly pointed by Алексей Кузнецов in comments, to avoid regexp one might use:

```
full_method_name = "#{method.owner.name}##{method.name}"
#⇒ "File::Stat#ctime"
```

Comment: @mudasobwa to build method full name without using regexp we could use  `method = foo.method(:ctime)   
# => File::Stat#ctime()   
full_method_name = "#{method.owner.name}##{method.name}"   
# => "File::Stat#ctime"`

Comment: I figured there MUST be a better way than the regexp, and started down this path too -- but it looks like #name actually fails on built-in core methods implemented in C in this case? Maybe it's a bug?  `File.method(:ctime).owner.name # => nil`. What?